# retrieving sum(column) from SQL query and adding to datagridviews after checking it as positive or negative

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have a form in my windows application(VS-2008 c#), where i need to retrieve sum(amount) and name for selected users, where each user might have multiple transactions,
this is the query i was using for this:

```
Select txt_name as Name,
       SUM(double_net_amt) as Amount 
       from match_transaction 
       where int_user_id IN (" + user_list + ") group by txt_name
```

but now i am expected to check the sum(amount) value and add it to a datagridview1 if it is positive, else add it to DGV2 if it is negative,

so with the group by clause, i can't figure out a way to do it, please help me.....:P/

thanxx in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate query for each grid, and alter each query to use `HAVING SUM(double_net_amount) > 0` (or < 0).

Like so:

```
select txt_name as Name,
       SUM(double_net_amt) as Amount 
from match_transaction 
where int_user_id IN (" + user_list + ") 
group by txt_name
having SUM(double_net_amt) > 0
```